# Date Period PHP

Tags: php, date

I want to render dates period base on start date and end date, for example:

Input:

- Start date: 30/12/2017
- End date: 31/03/2017
- Interval: every month

Output I want:

1. 30/12/2017
2. 30/01/2018
3. 30/03/2018 (February is missing because it not have 30th)

There my code:

```
function period_days($start_date, $int, $end_date){
    $begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
    $end = new DateTime( $end_date );

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($int);
    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end->modify( '+1 day' ));
    return $period;
}
echo period_days('30-12-2017', '1 month', '31-03-2018');
```

Result return wrong (3rd should be "2018-03-30"):

```
"2017-12-30 00:00:00" 
"2018-01-30 00:00:00"
"2018-03-02 00:00:00"
```

---

*Edit: Explain about Input:*

**Start date** format can be '31/12/2017' or 'first Monday of January 2018' or 'third Tuesday of December 2017' or '28 December 2017' ...

**Interval** can be '1 day', '1 month', '2 months', '1 year' ...

**End date** format is d-m-Y '01/12/2018'

I use this function to add schedule recurring event, something like plugin The Event Calendar, you guys can see example on https://wpshindig.com/events/community/add

Comment: What's wrong about it? The date format? March 2 instead of March 3? What have you tried. Did you let it run for a few years to see more of a pattern develop to spot what's actually wrong?

Comment: Hi @JasonB, You can see on my question the correct Output I really want, it should be show 30/03/2018 instead 02/03/2018 (the 3rd result wrong)

Comment: Will it always be the 30th?

Comment: Nope. It base on start date Input and interval month. For example start date is 31/12/2017 the results will be 31/01/2018, 31/03/2018, 31/05/2018 ....

Comment: Okay - we're getting somewhere. Seems like DatePeriod isn't the route to go. I'll whip up a function that should do this for you.

Comment: I've just update explain about Input format, it maybe make the question more clear to understand

Comment: Seems like it's getting much more complex... You may want to repost the question after another attempt with more sample data and expected outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

I could suggest you a work around.
Since DatePeriod breaks for February, we could get Year and month and append date separately. But this will only be working for **one year**.
Example :

```
   function periodDays($start_date, $int, $end_date){
    $begin = new DateTime($start_date);
    $end = new DateTime($end_date);
    $startDay = $begin->format("d");

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($int);
    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
    foreach($period as $date){
        echo $date->format("Y-m-") .$startDay. "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function is not correct 100%, it return wrong if Start date is 31-12-2017. But your idea help me a lot. Develop from your function and I have correct function now. Thanks!!!